# How to use purgeCSS with vueJs cli project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, webpack, vue-cli-3

I'm working on a Vue project build with Vue CLI 3. Of course, optimizations are important to me so I'd like to use purgecss to remove the unused CSS when building to the production.

I've followed what is written in this page https://purgecss.com/guides/vue.html#use-the-vue-cli-plugin. But after that whenever I try to build my project using `npm run build` I got this error and the build process is interrupted.[image]

Here's my `postcss.config.js` file. Note: this file is created automatically on following the above guide.

```js
const IN_PRODUCTION = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    IN_PRODUCTION && require("@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss");
    ({
      content: [`./public/**/*.html`, `./src/**/*.vue`],
      defaultExtractor(content) {
        const contentWithoutStyleBlocks = content.replace(/<style[^]+?<\/style>/gi, '')
        return contentWithoutStyleBlocks.match(/[A-Za-z0-9-_/:]*[A-Za-z0-9-_/]+/g) || []
      },
      whitelist: [],
      whitelistPatterns: [/-(leave|enter|appear)(|-(to|from|active))$/, /^(?!(|.*?:)cursor-move).+-move$/, /^router-link(|-exact)-active$/, /data-v-.*/],
    })
  ],
};
```

**NOTE**: I think that during the build process It can't find out the `@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss` plugin because of the default in the Vue cli projects  `@` is an alias for `src` folder, so it's looking in the `src` folder and not `node_modules`. But I'm not sure if this is the real problem